# How to represent this structure in a model?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit2 in order to get news of a blog, each news has **n** exercises to learn Spanish that have the structure of the code below:

**Exercises response part**

```
"exercises": {
      "number_of_exercises": 2,
      "exercise1": {
        "title": "Ejercicio de comprensión B.1 (Comprehension B.1)",
        "question1": "La noticia habla...",
        "answer1_1": "de un test para evaluar la inteligencia humana.",
        "answer1_2": "de un descubrimiento científico relacionado con el ser humano.",
        "answer1_3": "del descubrimiento de una nueva especie animal.",
        "correctAnswer1": "de un descubrimiento científico relacionado con el ser humano.",
        "question2": "Los genes identificados...",
        "answer2_1": "pueden explicar algunos comportamientos sociales del ser humano.",
        "answer2_2": "explican el funcionamiento completo del cerebro.",
        "answer2_3": "están relacionados con la inteligencia.",
        "correctAnswer2": "están relacionados con la inteligencia.",
        "question3": "Este descubrimiento...",
        "answer3_1": "no aportará nada a las investigaciones sobre el cerebro.",
        "answer3_2": "podría ofrecer nuevos datos sobre el funcionamiento del cerebro.",
        "answer3_3": "no es muy importante para la biología.",
        "correctAnswer3": "podría ofrecer nuevos datos sobre el funcionamiento del cerebro.",
        "question4": "Según el texto, los científicos ya saben todo sobre los procesos cognitivos.",
        "answer4_1": "No se sabe.",
        "answer4_2": "Verdadero.",
        "answer4_3": "Falso.",
        "correctAnswer4": "Falso."
      },
      "exercise2": {
        "title": "Ejercicio de vocabulario B.2 (Vocabulary B.2)",
        "question1": "Relacionas 'cognitivo' con...",
        "answer1_1": "la empatía.",
        "answer1_2": "el conocimiento.",
        "answer1_3": "una congestión.",
        "correctAnswer1": "el conocimiento.",
        "question2": "'Cohorte' es igual que...",
        "answer2_1": "'conjunto'.",
        "answer2_2": "'comprensión'.",
        "answer2_3": "'finalización'.",
        "correctAnswer2": "'conjunto'.",
        "question3": "Lo contrario de 'específico' es...",
        "answer3_1": "'genérico'.",
        "answer3_2": "'aleatorio'.",
        "answer3_3": "'concreto'.",
        "correctAnswer3": "'genérico'.",
        "question4": "El 'genoma' está relacionado con el ADN.",
        "answer4_1": "No se sabe.",
        "answer4_2": "Falso.",
        "answer4_3": "Verdadero.",
        "correctAnswer4": "Verdadero."
      }
    }
```

As the number of exercises varies (sometimes 1 or more) I do not know how to represent them in a class by the type of structure they have.

Could you guys please help me?

I already tried to create a class, but with subclasses Exercise1, Exercise2, etc ... I'm looking for the best way to complete this requirement

Comment: You json must return an array of exercises instead of a variable number of attributes.

Comment: Yep, it would be great @JonathanAste but sadly customer does not plan to make changes to API :-(

Comment: Ideally, `exercises` and `questions` should both be arrays. The question objects would contain an array of possible answers

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try {
    ArrayList<Exercise> exercises = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(yourJson);
    int exerciseQuantity = json.getInt("number_of_exercises");
    for (int i = 1; i <= exerciseQuantity; i++) {
        Exercise e = json.get("exercise".concat(String.valueOf(i)));
        if (e != null) {
            exercises.add(e);
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Retrofit, you're probably using Gson too.
At least, Gson allows to implement wonderful stuff even for badly designed JSON documents.

First off, you can design your proper object model in order to make it convenient to use.

```java
final class ExerciseWrapper {

    final List<Exercise> exercises;

    ExerciseWrapper(final List<Exercise> exercises) {
        this.exercises = exercises;
    }

}
```

```java
final class Exercise {

    final String title;
    final List<Question> questions;

    Exercise(final String title, final List<Question> questions) {
        this.title = title;
        this.questions = questions;
    }

}
```

```java
final class Question {

    final String question;
    final List<String> answers;
    final int correctAnswer;

    Question(final String question, final List<String> answers, final int correctAnswer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.answers = answers;
        this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    }

}
```

Now, define some interfaces to implement various strategies for the deserializers.
These are trivial, and you can use anything like that if you have any (for example, if you're using Google Guava, just use `Function` and `Supplier`).

```java
interface IFunction<T, R> {

    R apply(T t);

}
```

```java
interface ISupplier<T> {

    T get();

}
```

Next, you have to "unflatten" the properties that should be arrays if the given JSON would be well-designed.
The `extract` methods below try to iterate over each object property and check if it can extract an index.
If an index is extracted, they try to ensure the lists size are enough to fit all elements.
Once the list size is fine, they try to obtain a value from elsewhere via a strategy.

```java
final class Extractors {

    private Extractors() {
    }

    static <R> List<R> extract(
            final JsonObject jsonObject,
            final IFunction<? super String, Integer> scanner,
            final IFunction<? super JsonElement, ? extends R> mapper
    ) {
        final List<R> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for ( final Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : jsonObject.entrySet() ) {
            final Integer i = scanner.apply(entry.getKey());
            if ( i != null ) {
                ensureSize(list, i, () -> null);
                list.set(i - 1, mapper.apply(entry.getValue()));
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    static <R> List<List<R>> extract(
            final JsonObject jsonObject,
            final IFunction<? super String, Integer> superScanner,
            final IFunction<? super String, Integer> subScanner,
            final IFunction<? super JsonElement, ? extends R> mapper
    ) {
        final List<List<R>> superList = new ArrayList<>();
        for ( final Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : jsonObject.entrySet() ) {
            final Integer superI = superScanner.apply(entry.getKey());
            if ( superI != null ) {
                final Integer subI = subScanner.apply(entry.getKey());
                if ( subI != null ) {
                    ensureSize(superList, superI, ArrayList::new);
                    final List<R> subList = superList.get(superI - 1);
                    ensureSize(subList, subI, () -> null);
                    subList.set(subI - 1, mapper.apply(entry.getValue()));
                }
            }
        }
        return superList;
    }

    private static <T> void ensureSize(final Collection<? super T> collection, final int size, final ISupplier<? extends T> defaultValueSupplier) {
        while ( collection.size() < size ) {
            collection.add(defaultValueSupplier.get());
        }
    }

}
```

The next class represents a couple of string-to-integer mapping strategy factory methods in order to be used in the `extract` methods above:

```java
final class Scanners {

    private Scanners() {
    }

    static IFunction<String, Integer> scanByPattern(final String pattern) {
        return scanByPattern(Pattern.compile(pattern));
    }

    static IFunction<String, Integer> scanByPattern(final Pattern pattern) {
        return name -> {
            final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
            if ( !matcher.matches() ) {
                return null;
            }
            return parseInt(matcher.group(1));
        };
    }

}
```

Those were easy parts.
Writing a custom deserializer may be more complicated.

```java
final class ExerciseJsonDeserializer
        implements JsonDeserializer<Exercise> {

    private static final JsonDeserializer<Exercise> exerciseJsonDeserializer = new ExerciseJsonDeserializer();

    private static final IFunction<String, Integer> questionScanner = scanByPattern("question(\\d+)");
    private static final IFunction<String, Integer> correctAnswerScanner = scanByPattern("correctAnswer(\\d+)");
    private static final IFunction<String, Integer> answerScanner1 = scanByPattern("answer(\\d+)_\\d+");
    private static final IFunction<String, Integer> answerScanner2 = scanByPattern("answer\\d+_(\\d+)");

    private ExerciseJsonDeserializer() {
    }

    static JsonDeserializer<Exercise> getExerciseJsonDeserializer() {
        return exerciseJsonDeserializer;
    }

    @Override
    public Exercise deserialize(final JsonElement jsonElement, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        final JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        return new Exercise(
                jsonObject.getAsJsonPrimitive("title").getAsString(),
                mergeQuestionParts(
                        extract(jsonObject, questionScanner, JsonElement::getAsString),
                        extract(jsonObject, answerScanner1, answerScanner2, JsonElement::getAsString),
                        extract(jsonObject, correctAnswerScanner, JsonElement::getAsString)
                )
        );
    }

    private static List<Question> mergeQuestionParts(final Iterable<String> questionTitles, final Iterable<List<String>> answers,
            final Iterable<String> correctAnswers) {
        final Iterator<String> questionIterator = questionTitles.iterator();
        final Iterator<List<String>> answerIterator = answers.iterator();
        final Iterator<String> correctAnswerIterator = correctAnswers.iterator();
        final List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
        while ( questionIterator.hasNext() && answerIterator.hasNext() && correctAnswerIterator.hasNext() ) {
            final String question = questionIterator.next();
            final List<String> rawAnswers = answerIterator.next();
            final String correctAnswer = correctAnswerIterator.next();
            questions.add(new Question(question, rawAnswers, rawAnswers.indexOf(correctAnswer)));
        }
        return questions;
    }
}
```

```java
final class ExerciseWrapperJsonDeserializer
        implements JsonDeserializer<ExerciseWrapper> {

    private static final JsonDeserializer<ExerciseWrapper> exerciseWrapperJsonDeserializer = new ExerciseWrapperJsonDeserializer();

    private static final IFunction<String, Integer> exerciseScanner = scanByPattern("exercise(\\d+)");

    private ExerciseWrapperJsonDeserializer() {
    }

    static JsonDeserializer<ExerciseWrapper> getExerciseWrapperJsonDeserializer() {
        return exerciseWrapperJsonDeserializer;
    }

    @Override
    public ExerciseWrapper deserialize(final JsonElement jsonElement, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        final JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        return new ExerciseWrapper(
                extract(jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("exercises"), exerciseScanner, je -> context.deserialize(je, Exercise.class))
        );
    }

}
```

How it's used in Java 8:

```
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(ExerciseWrapper.class, getExerciseWrapperJsonDeserializer())
        .registerTypeAdapter(Exercise.class, getExerciseJsonDeserializer())
        .setPrettyPrinting()
        .create();

public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = getPackageResourceJsonReader(Q44165271.class, "exercise.json") ) {
        final ExerciseWrapper exerciseWrapper = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, ExerciseWrapper.class);
        exerciseWrapper.exercises.forEach(exercise -> {
            System.out.println(exercise.title);
            exercise.questions.forEach(question -> {
                System.out.println("\t" + question.question);
                question.answers.forEach(answer -> System.out.println("\t\t" + answer));
                System.out.println("\t" + (question.correctAnswer + 1));
            });
        });
        System.out.println("-----");
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(exerciseWrapper));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Ejercicio de comprensión B.1 (Comprehension B.1)
    La noticia habla...
        de un test para evaluar la inteligencia humana.
        de un descubrimiento científico relacionado con el ser humano.
        del descubrimiento de una nueva especie animal.
    2
    Los genes identificados...
        pueden explicar algunos comportamientos sociales del ser humano.
        explican el funcionamiento completo del cerebro.
        están relacionados con la inteligencia.
    3
    Este descubrimiento...
        no aportará nada a las investigaciones sobre el cerebro.
        podría ofrecer nuevos datos sobre el funcionamiento del cerebro.
        no es muy importante para la biología.
    2
    Según el texto, los científicos ya saben todo sobre los procesos cognitivos.
        No se sabe.
        Verdadero.
        Falso.
    3
Ejercicio de vocabulario B.2 (Vocabulary B.2)
    Relacionas 'cognitivo' con...
        la empatía.
        el conocimiento.
        una congestión.
    2
    'Cohorte' es igual que...
        'conjunto'.
        'comprensión'.
        'finalización'.
    1
    Lo contrario de 'específico' es...
        'genérico'.
        'aleatorio'.
        'concreto'.
    1
    El 'genoma' está relacionado con el ADN.
        No se sabe.
        Falso.
        Verdadero.
    3
-----
{
  "exercises": [
    {
      "title": "Ejercicio de comprensión B.1 (Comprehension B.1)",
      "questions": [
        {
          "question": "La noticia habla...",
          "answers": [
            "de un test para evaluar la inteligencia humana.",
            "de un descubrimiento científico relacionado con el ser humano.",
            "del descubrimiento de una nueva especie animal."
          ],
          "correctAnswer": 1
        },
        {
          "question": "Los genes identificados...",
          "answers": [
            "pueden explicar algunos comportamientos sociales del ser humano.",
            "explican el funcionamiento completo del cerebro.",
            "están relacionados con la inteligencia."
          ],
          "correctAnswer": 2
        },
        {
          "question": "Este descubrimiento...",
          "answers": [
            "no aportará nada a las investigaciones sobre el cerebro.",
            "podría ofrecer nuevos datos sobre el funcionamiento del cerebro.",
            "no es muy importante para la biología."
          ],
          "correctAnswer": 1
        },
        {
          "question": "Según el texto, los científicos ya saben todo sobre los procesos cognitivos.",
          "answers": [
            "No se sabe.",
            "Verdadero.",
            "Falso."
          ],
          "correctAnswer": 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Ejercicio de vocabulario B.2 (Vocabulary B.2)",
      "questions": [
        {
          "question": "Relacionas \u0027cognitivo\u0027 con...",
          "answers": [
            "la empatía.",
            "el conocimiento.",
            "una congestión."
          ],
          "correctAnswer": 1
        },
        {
          "question": "\u0027Cohorte\u0027 es igual que...",
          "answers": [
            "\u0027conjunto\u0027.",
            "\u0027comprensión\u0027.",
            "\u0027finalización\u0027."
          ],
          "correctAnswer": 0
        },
        {
          "question": "Lo contrario de \u0027específico\u0027 es...",
          "answers": [
            "\u0027genérico\u0027.",
            "\u0027aleatorio\u0027.",
            "\u0027concreto\u0027."
          ],
          "correctAnswer": 0
        },
        {
          "question": "El \u0027genoma\u0027 está relacionado con el ADN.",
          "answers": [
            "No se sabe.",
            "Falso.",
            "Verdadero."
          ],
          "correctAnswer": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```